# TYPO3 8.7.1 templating problems

Tags: typo3, templating, t3editor

I started using TYPO3 8.7.1 some days ago - no prior experiences in TYPO3.

I am at the point that I am using the t3editor to create a first test template using the guide that's been offered on the official page, which is for version 7. Are there huge differences in templating between those two versions, because I am only getting a blank page and even my source code shows nothing in between the body tags.

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE

# Define that we use a Template and where it is located
page.10 = TEMPLATE

page.10 {
template = FILE
template.file = fileadmin/tmp/home.html
}

# Insert shortcut icon in the head of the website
page.shortcutIcon = fileadmin/img/favicon.ico

# Insert stylesheet in the head of the website
page.includeCSS.base = fileadmin/css/style.css
```

On that note I have another question. I can't seem to find regularity for the highlighting colors used by the t3editor, but at the same time I can't find any errors in this snippet.

Can anyone help?

Best regards

Comment: You don't define any subparts. So all between the body tags in the template is removed and nothing inserted. I recommend to switch to FLUIDTEMPLATE as modern templating version.

Answer (score 0):

An example with FLUIDTEMPLATE:

In TypoScript Setup:

```
page = PAGE
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        template = FILE
        template.file = fileadmin/Templates/Html/Page/Templates/Default.html
        layoutRootPath = fileadmin/Templates/Html/Page/Layouts/
        variables {
            content < styles.content.get
        }
    }
}
```

fileadmin/Templates/Html/Page/Layouts/Default.html

```
<f:render section="Main" />
```

fileadmin/Templates/Html/Page/Templates/Default.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Template Default</title>
</head>
<body>
<f:layout name="Default"/>

<f:section name="Main">
            <f:format.raw>{content}</f:format.raw>
</f:section>
</body>
```

Then insert content and show the page.

Comment: Danke für die Antwort, werd's probieren. Gibt es fürs fluid templating auch ein Tutorial, denn dein Codebeispiel verstehe ich nur sehr schwer. :)

Comment: Simple Google search: typo3 fluid tutorial